# ArrayList populated by user imput to ComboBox (Select JPS)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

This is what Im trying to do, a user inputs a name, the name is added to an ArrayList placed on a servlet, then the names should be shown in the combo box, below is what I have. It trows the error "stray c foreach start tag"

INDEX.JSP

```
<body>
    <form action="ServletGuardar.do" method="post">
        Name<input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
    </form>
    <hr>
    <form action="ServletGuardar.do" method="post">
    Names<select name="database1">
        <c:forEach items="${lista}" var="databaseValue">
            <option value="${databaseValue}">
                ${databaseValue}
            </option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    </form>
</body>
```

SERVLET

```
ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
String name = request.getParameter("name");
lista.add(name);

request.setAttribute("lista", "lista");

request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: Hi, the combobox (Select) doesnt show anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and made it working by changing following things

1. If your jsp is not having reference to the tag library then add it
2. At server side , you didn't added the ArrayList object to request as
   object rather you added it as String as the other answer already mentioned.
3. Also check when you submit the name from the first form, print it and
   check in the logs if you getting the name value on server side.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="./ServletGuardar.do" method="post">
        Name<input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
    </form>
    <hr>
    <form action="/ServletGuardar.do" method="post">

    Names<select name="database1">
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="databaseValue">
            <option value="${databaseValue}">
                ${databaseValue}
            </option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Servlet's doGet Method**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        System.out.println("name=" + name);

        list.add(name);

        request.setAttribute("list", list);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

        // response.getWriter().append("name="+name+".Served at:
        // ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }
```

**web.xml**

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ServletGuardar</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletGuardar.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: @Exit let me know if you are still facing the challenge

Comment: I folow your Steps and now works, but only display one input in the combobox

Comment: Numbee of options appearing in combo box depends on how many objects you added in the array list in servlet, add more objects in servlet then try